# Any scrum/agile project management tools we can use?

Tags: project-management, agile, scrum

Please recommend a scrum/agile project management tool. First, it should be able to be installed or deployed on my local computer.  Additionally, it should be free, no need for complete unlimited usage, just that it can support 5 users and some scrum project functions, such as "kanban".

I found some answers of other questions like mine. Some of the tools which have been recommended are too old, so please recommend newer tools for me.  And if it has a nice look that would be better, something like [scrumwise](http://www.scrumwise.com/) or [targetprocess](http://www.targetprocess.com/).

Must haves:

1. local applications
2. free
3. kanban

Comment: you asked the same question one day before you asked this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729113/please-recommend-a-scrum-agile-project-management-toole.

Comment: Wall, post-its, and a sharipe.

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it should be at programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Nakilon actually it should be closed with the "tool recommendation" reason.

Comment: "closed as off topic" so do we have a place where these type of questions are "on topic" hmm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're wanting a local application, I'm assuming that your team is all located in the same place.

If so, I'd advise against using tools. As the agile manifesto says: "We value Individuals and Interactions over processes and tools". I'd urge you to consider co-locating your team(s), improving communication, using cards, physical boards and information radiators.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You get it, our team is at the same place. Your idea is good idea and I want to do so too. But I want a toole can archive the tasks(stories) and make modify easier. Most important thing, can generate a beautiful report to my boss.

Comment: I'd still recommend using physical cards, boards and information radiators. Then, if you need a pretty report, try something like Excel. Just a side thought - is your boss bought-in to using Scrum? If not, I suggest you have a larger issue to resolve than providing reports

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using [Eylean board](http://www.eylean.com) as it is the most visual scrum board compared to the competitors. And according to scrum you need to have a visible and transparent process inside your team. Also this software allows mixing other methodologies as well.

It is free of charge for personal use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try **Yodiz**, you can have up to 3 free users and it's one of the most intuitive with amazing UX. Every month they add more features to their platform. A few of the important features they have are following.

- Collaboration Tools (Chat, Discussion, in-line comments)
- Board, they have slick boards to manage your user stories and tasks.
- User story management is as easy as it gets. Awesome backlog with priority and filtering
  features.
- Import/Export data to or from Jira, Pivotal and many other systems.
- Three (3) free users with full features.
- Report, they have detailed reporting, that makes progress and time tracking so easy.

Over all it's great tool. It's worth to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.simple-kanban.com 
This seems like it meets your requirements. There are other possibilities if you will accept a hosted solution rather than a local install.

Comment: Thanks, I want local applications because my network is behind a company proxy firewall, I can't visit many website normally.